# I had a netty dns problem and I solved it but I don't know why it solved it

Tags: netty, spring-cloud-gateway

While using spring cloud gateway, there was an error where netty could not check DNS.
however, I found the following code on the Internet, added it, and it was solved. I feel dizzy.

```
    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return HttpClient.create().resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE);
    }
```

Comment: Hello there! Please, which version of Spring did you use here to get this to work?
I've added this configuration for Spring Boot 3.2.3 and it doesn't still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1431 It is probably related to this issue. I needed to do the similar walkaround too.

Comment: You probably mean "workaround", not "walkaround" :) Further, it would help the question author and other readers to explain *why* the workaround solves it.